# What happens if I capture a local variable by reference, and it goes out of scope?

Tags: c++, lambda, c++11

Suppose I use a lambda as a callback function, and when creating the lambda, I capture a local function variable by reference. Now suppose that the lambda object does not get executed until after that local function variable goes out of scope. What happens?

I realize that it would be pretty stupid for someone to do so if there's a chance of it happening, but I am almost positive that someone would end up doing it.

Comment: I'm not familiar with c++11 but for any other language I've used, capturing the variable by definition means that it doesn't go out of scope for as long as it is captured (there are any [indirect] references to it).

Comment: Not in C++. Returning a lambda that captures a local variable by reference means that reference will no longer be valid once the enclosing function returns. Undefined behavior ensues.

Comment: Functions themselves are static and hence always valid. But a `void (**)()` *can* become dangling. What else?

Comment: @Joop, I think the questioner stores a function pointer into a local variable and captures that variable. Even if the function pointer will arguably still be valid, the reference to the local variable won't.

Comment: @RepDbg, lifting doesn't occur in C++11, dangling references result in undefined behavior. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6775174/lambda-should-capturing-const-reference-by-reference-yield-undefined-behaviour.

Comment: I recently got caught by this but my compiler (VC2019) didn't give me any warnings, which would have saved some effort.  Is there a warning in VC or gcc/clang that would tell me about this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, that would be following a dangling reference. It sounds like you're worried about interface design: "I am almost positive that someone would end up doing it." Please don't reject lambdas and `std::function` on this basis, as they are no more dangerous than any other alternative. Lambdas are just a simpler way to define local functors. `std::function` is the best interface to persistent, polymorphic functors, lambda or not.

The scope issue is why it's easier to capture by value. The user won't get a reference unless they write `&`. Of course, the danger is that someone would get in the habit of starting all their lambda functions with `[&]`, since references are "faster." Hopefully any such person would learn their lesson soon enough… although some pointer-happy folks are just incorrigible.

Answer (score 12):

The same thing that happens when you return a reference to a local variable: undefined behavior.