# C++ Lambda capture messing up local variable value

Tags: c++, variables, lambda, local, capture

I am not sure whether this is a VS 2010 problem or I am misunderstanding something completely. I am creating a boost thread via a lambda function which needs to modify a local variable:

```
    auto oCurrTime( boost::posix_time::microsec_clock::universal_time() );
    auto spRequestSequenceThread = make_unique<boost::thread>( [&oCurrTime, this]()
    {
        while ( !checkAgainstSpecificTime(oCurrTime) )
        {
            ...
        }
        :
        :
    }
```

Before creating the thread, oCurrTime is something like 2864273654234872634, but within the thread this value gets lost and oCurrTime immediately is something like 487465847564875465, rendering the while loop (where a time difference to some specific Time is evaluated) useless.

Thanks a lot for help.

P.S.: The above code is part of a function of a class

Comment: What does your main thread do after launching this lambda thread? Are you sure that `oCurrTime` doesn't go out of existence, and/or be concurrently accessed by the main thread?

Comment: Concurrent usage ist definitely not the case. But I think you are right about the existence thingy, as the functions probably returns before the threads ends. I did not consider this and will check this immediately...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It look like you execute your thread from class method - you provide `this` in lambda capture list. This also means `oCurrTime` is local variable, so if you capture it by reference : you use `&`, then when your thread executes `oCurrTime` will be removed from stack because scope when it was defined already ended.

The solution is to pass `oCurrTime` by value (remove `&`) if it is possible, or join your thread before your method ends - also if that is possible. You could also make `oCurrTime` a class variable.

Comment: Yep, as in the answer above, I guess it is an out of scope problem. I will try making it a member var...

Comment: @gilgamash you could capture by value

Comment: Yes, I could do that, but the value gets changed within the thread (which I did not make clear by the code above), so this is not an option for this specific case.

Comment: @gilgamash you can modify captured values if you declare the lambda as `mutable`.

Comment: OK, I forgot about that. Or better said: I try avoiding mutable where possible.

Answer (score 0):

As you're capturing it by reference `[&oCurrTime]`
If `oCurrTime` goes out of scope you will have a [dangling reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9488129/in-c11-lambdas-what-happens-if-i-capture-a-local-variable-by-reference-and-i).

One solution could be to capture by value.